# Is the size prefix for each buffer or entire program?

Tags: c++, serialization, flatbuffers

I'm streaming flat buffers over network, so each buffer is size prefixed, by `FinishSizePrefixedFoo(fbb, msg)`, but I notice this size prefix is not the size of the message structure `msg`, it is the size of the whole buffer builder. For example:

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
flatbuffers::Offset<Message> msg;
msg = ns::CreateMessage(fbb, ...);
FinishSizePrefixedMessageBuffer(fbb, msg);
flatbuffers::uoffset_t len = flatbuffers::ReadScalar<flatbuffers::uoffset_t>(fbb.GetBufferPointer());
std::cout << "Buffer size is " << fbb.GetSize() << " size prefix is " << len << std::endl;
flatbuffers::Offset<Message> msg2;
msg2 = ns::CreateMessage(fbb, ...);
FinishSizePrefixedMessageBuffer(fbb, msg2);
len = flatbuffers::ReadScalar<flatbuffers::uoffset_t>(fbb.GetBufferPointer());
std::cout << "Buffer size is " << fbb.GetSize() << " size prefix is " << len << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
Buffer size is 84 size prefix is 80
Buffer size is 168 size prefix is 164
```

But the expected output is:

```
Buffer size is 84 size prefix is 80
Buffer size is 168 size prefix is 80
```

Otherwise there is no way to separate the two messages.

I'm using this size prefix for verifier and deserialisation, e.g.:

```
buf[4] = recv(4);
uoffset_t len = ReadScalar(buf);
buf[4..len+4] = recv(len);
msg = GetSizePrefixedMessage(buf);
```

When I read the size is 164, a message of size 164 is expected to follow, while in fact is is two messages of 80 bytes each. Is this flatbuffers' bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you develop with asserts on, as that would have already told you that the above code is not correct.

When you call `Finish` on a builder, you cannot serialize more data into it, unless you call `Clear`. So in this case the second buffer also contains a copy of the first buffer. The assert would have told you that.

Of course, you can also use 2 `FlatBufferBuilder` instances, if you want to easily keep both buffers available.

Comment: I enabled #define FLATBUFFERS_ASSERT, no problem is reported.

Comment: No, you should make sure you test in debug mode on your platform. Every C/C++ compiler on every platform will stop at a failure of `assert()` calls. You for some reason are not getting them.

Comment: It is just that assert is not hit. I don't find any reference in the documents saying Finish is for entire builder, i think it means finish current buffer.

Comment: Yes, they are not hit because you're compiling in "release" mode or some other compiler setting that turns them off.

Comment: And a builder holds a single buffer.